# System.Diagnostics.Process Hangs on Network Files Only

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, process, system.diagnostics

```
Dim myProcess As System.Diagnostics.Process = New System.Diagnostics.Process()

myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Program Files (x86)\IrfanView\i_view32.exe"
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = sFileName
myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
myProcess.Start()
```

The code above to open a tif image in Irfanview works perfectly when the file is on a local drive. If the file is on a network share Irfanview will appear to be hung with a (Not Responding) in the title bar. This is new behavior with Windows 7. On Windows XP machines, on the same network, I don't have this problem.

Any idea why?

Greg

[Edit]

I also tried the code below with no luck and tried another image viewer beside irfanview and had the same results. With this code irfanview tells me it is not a valid file and displays the exact path and file name to the file. Very irritating. The old Windows API ShellExecute will not launch the program. Grrrrrr!!!!

```
Dim domain As String = {domain}
Dim uname As String = {username}
Dim passwordtx As String = {password}
Dim password As New System.Security.SecureString()
Dim c As Char
For Each c In passwordtx
    password.AppendChar(c)
Next c

Dim myProcess As System.Diagnostics.Process = New System.Diagnostics.Process()

myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Program Files (x86)\IrfanView\i_view32.exe"
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = sFileName
myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\"
myProcess.StartInfo.UserName = uname
myProcess.StartInfo.Domain = domain
myProcess.StartInfo.Password = password
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
myProcess.Start()
```

Comment: Check the permissions on irfanview? I just tried the first example, and it worked fine. When the network permissions were not in place, and when the jpg file was missing, irfanview gave an error. Otherwise, irfanview loaded the file. (vs2008, win7-64)

Comment: Thanks for testing the code. To be clear, you were loading an image off a network share and not off a local drive? For me it works fine if the image is on a local drive.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by 'Check permissions on irfanview'. Permissions on the folder where the executable is?

Comment: I see you got it. I loaded a file form the network. I meant to make sure that irfanview didn't require admin privilege or something like that, but of course that's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

It had nothing to do with the code. The problem was there were too many files in the folder and irfanview was trying to catalog them all, or doing something like that. I will need to break up the files by month or something.

Greg